# Meteorite change "manually" installed packages to automatically installed

Tags: meteor, meteorite, package-managers

I reinstalled my system, and now I get this error when trying to update in meteorite.

```
Package iron-router has been ignored because it has been manually installed in /packages
```

This happens for all my packages, and I can't seem to figure out how to get meteorite to re-initialize them. It also won't let me remove, then add the packages saying:

```
Package iron-router can't be removed from packages/ because it has been manually installed.
```

Comment: Check the `/packages` subdirectory in your project. In general it should only contain symbolic links. Check if this is the case. If you have nothing important in there, you can also try removing this directory and see if `meteorite` start to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this line](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/lib/dependencies/package.js#L176), your package is not a symbolic link.

Try the following in your app directory:

```
rm -r packages/iron-router
rm smart.lock
mrt add iron-router
mrt install .
```

Comment: Just deleting everything in the packages directory worked fine, thanks a lot :)